# Pandas drop duplicates when values in other columns are same

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
Col1    Col2    Val
T1      L2      1
T1      L2      1
T1      G3      3
G3      G3      4
G3      G3      6
G3      L2      7
L2      L2      8
L2      L2      9
```

I want to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Val
T1      L2      1
T1      L2      1
T1      G3      3
G3      G3      4
G3      L2      7
L2      L2      8
```

I want to drop duplicate rows based on column `Val` only when `Col1` and `Col2` are same.

I am trying to use the following `df.drop_duplicates(subset='Val', keep='first')` but have been unable to add the condition on `Col1` and `Col2`.

I am not sure how to approach the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can check for rows where `Col1 == Col2` and where both columns are duplicated:

```
df[~(df["Col1"].eq(df["Col2"]) & df.duplicated(subset=["Col1", "Col2"]))]
```

```
  Col1 Col2  Val
0   T1   L2    1
1   T1   L2    1
2   T1   G3    3
3   G3   G3    4
5   G3   L2    7
6   L2   L2    8
```